# How to execute multiple populate in Express js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, populate

I am trying to execute multiple populate, so far, only last populate is executing.

here is my code,

```
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  Order.find()
    .select("product quantity _id")
    .populate('product', 'name')
    .populate('product', 'price')
    .populate('product','productImage')
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
      res.status(200).json({
        count: docs.length,
        orders: docs.map(doc => {
          return {
            _id: doc._id,
            product: doc.product,
            productImage: doc.productImage,
            name: doc.name,
            price: doc.price,
            quantity: doc.quantity,
            request: {
              type: "GET",
              url: "http://localhost:3000/orders/" + doc._id
            }
          };
        })
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

I am only getting productImage. If I remove productImage, I am getting a price. In short only last populate is working

I am getting this as an output

```
> {
>     "count": 2,
>     "orders": [
>         {
>             "_id": "5ba8cb0016e76b50288e67ba",
>             "product": {
>                 "_id": "5ba8c93916e76b50288e67b9"
>             },
>             "quantity": 2,
>             "request": {
>                 "type": "GET",
>                 "url": "http://localhost:3000/orders/5ba8cb0016e76b50288e67ba"
>             }
>         },
>         {
>             "_id": "5baa1c5c121b9350d309ce6a",
>             "product": {
>                 "_id": "5baa1a96d6fc025019a15287",
>                 "productImage": "uploads/2018-09-25T11:23:02.744ZScreenshot from 2018-08-07
> 11-27-31.png"
>             },
>             "quantity": 1,
>             "request": {
>                 "type": "GET",
>                 "url": "http://localhost:3000/orders/5baa1c5c121b9350d309ce6a"
>             }
>         }
>     ]
```

Comment: What is this populate? What is it returning?

Comment: please see my updated question @Sreehari

Comment: You need to give some insight on your mongoose schemas otherwise everyone is just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Mongoose documentation, if you call populate() multiple times with same path then only the last one will take effect.

If you are using mongoose v3, I believe the below code should work for you.

```
Order.find()
.select("product quantity _id")
.populate('product', 'name price productImage')
.exec()
.then(docs => {
     .....
     .....
})
```

Mongoose documentation reference.
 https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose

```
  Order.find()
    .select("product quantity _id")
    .populate('product', 'name')
    .populate('product', 'price')
    .populate('product','productImage')
    .exec()
```

isn't working because you're populating single specific field again and again for the same `refrence`.

**What is happening?**

1. product is populated with name field.
2. you again populate product with price field and overwrite the previous doc.
3. you again populate productImage field and overwrite the previous doc.

**What you need to do?**

```
  Order.find()
    .select("product quantity _id")
    .populate('product', 'name price producImage')
```

Call a single populate with [field name syntax](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) and also see [field selection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#field-selection).